# Help understanding the use of the First Isomorphism Theorem with regards to the special linear group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism, quotient-group

I'm reading a textbook (*Contemporary Abstract Algebra, 9th Edition*, Joseph A. Gallian), and it gave the following example:

> Recall that $SL(2,\mathbb{R})=\{A\in GL(2,\mathbb{R}\ |\det A=1)\}$ and let $H=\{A\in GL(2,\mathbb{R}\ |\det A=\pm 1)\}$. Then mapping $\Phi(A)=\det A$ fom $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ onto $\mathbb{R}^*$ shows that $GL(2,\mathbb{R})/SL(2,\mathbb{R})\approx\mathbb{R}^*$.

Here, $\mathbb{R}^*$ is used to represent the set of all real nonzero numbers.

Where I'm getting tripped is why $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ itself isn't simply homomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^*$. By definition, $A\in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ implies that $\det A\neq0$, and as we all know, $\det AB=\det A\det B$. This to me seems to imply that $GL(2,\mathbb{R})\approx \mathbb{R}^*$. How can a factor group *and* the group it is a subgroup of be homomorphic to the same group?

(Additionally, I think I'm still a bit fuzzy as to what $GL(2,\mathbb{R})/SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ actually *is*. To the best of my knowledge, I think it's the set of all cosets of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ in $GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ - that is, all the matrices $C$ where $AB=A'B'+C$, with $A,A'\in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$ and $B,B'\in SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. Is this an accurate way of thinking about the group?)

Comment: $H$ is not used or needed for this result, as far as I can see. It might be used in the book a different result after this result?

Comment: $\Phi(A)=1$ doesn't implies that $A=I$. Therefore, $\Phi$ is not injective.

Comment: It's only an isomorphism if $\det(A)=\det(B)$ implies $A=B.$ But $A=I,B=-I$ gives a clear example that this is not true.

Comment: So, $\Phi(A)=1$ doesn't implies that $A=I$ and thus, $\Phi$ is not injective... what is unclear ? @ThomasAndrews

Comment: An intuitive way to think about $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{R})/\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ is as partition of the general linear group into cosets of the same determinant. Considering two matrices are in the same coset if $AB^{-1} \in \text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$, two matrices are in the same coset if $\det(AB^{-1}) = \det(A)\det(B)^{-1} = 1$, showing that $\det A = \det B$.

Comment: Your definition of the cosets is a bit confused, and shows you might want to review that definition. What are $A,B,C,A',B'$ supposed to represent? While (left)-cosets of a subgroup $H$ of a group $G$ are often written as $gH$. where $g\in G,$ I often tend to think of them as equivalence classes  in $G$ modulo $H$ - extending the way we think of the integers modulo $n.$ So $g_1\sim g_2\pmod{H}$ is defined to mean $g_1^{-1}g_2\in H.$  Then the coset containing $g_1$ contains exactly the elements $g\in G$ such that $g_1^{-1}g\in H.$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews sorry, I cut off the bit from the book short - it went on to say that $GL(2,\mathbb{R})/H\approx\mathbb{R}^+$ with the mapping $\Phi(A)=(\det A)^2$. Thank you for all your help, I feel like I have a clearer understanding now!

Comment: Why isn't the set of people in bijection with the set of ages? After all, every person has an age. So we conclude there are only about 120 or so people on Earth! The answer is different people can have the same age. Similarly, different matrices can have the same determinant. The fact the determinant is a homomorphism doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The determinant map $\det\colon\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb R)\to\mathbb R^\ast$ defines a group homomorphism, so much is clear. This is just a reformulation of the fact that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$. This map is also clearly surjective since

$$
\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}r&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}\right)=r
$$

for any non-zero $r\in\mathbb R$. However, and here is the catch, this map is *not* injective; in fact, far from it. Note that for example $1\in\mathbb R^\ast$ has uncountably many pre-images given by

$$
\det\left(\begin{pmatrix}r&0\\0&r^{-1}\end{pmatrix}\right)=1
$$

for any non-zero $r\in\mathbb R$. And an *iso*morphism (the $\approx$ notation is usually reserved for isomorphisms) is by definition bijective. Hence, $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb R)\not\approx\mathbb R^\ast$; well, at least not along this particular homomorphism.

The First Isomorphism Theorem tells you how to fix this issue: just mod out the kernel! The kernel is by definition given by $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ as the identity element of $\mathbb R^\ast$ is $1$.

---

Regarding your question on the internal structure of the factor group.

Both $G=\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb R)$ and $K=\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ are *mutliplicative* groups. Given $A\in G$ its coset $AK$ is

$$
AK=\{AS\,|\,S\in K\}\,.
$$

Two elements in the factor group $G/K$ are the same if their representatives in $G$ differ by an element of $K$, i.e. $AK=BK$ iff $AB^{-1}\in K$. I think somewhere here you mixed up additive and multiplicative notions.